# syntax error or access violation 1064 php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT FROM menulist_tbl WHERE menulist_id=:MENUID");
        $stmt->bindValue(':MENUID',$menuid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

i have this is select statement but i get `syntax error or access violation 1064` in line 471 which is the line `$stmt->execute();` i cant see the error because i am using this same statement before but i dont get error i am wondering why i get it now

Comment: ,Please check my answer,It could resolve your issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what you are selecting which you have not. If you need to select all columns then

```
select * from table_name
```

If you need to select some specific columns then

```
select col1,col2 from  table_name
```

In your case you may have it as

```
SELECT * FROM menulist_tbl WHERE menulist_id=:MENUID
```

or if you want some specific columns to be selected instead of *

Comment: 7 mins to tick answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what you are selecting from table. Use * for all fields or specify the name of field.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE

SELECT filed1,filed2 FROM TABLE
```